# Cannot find a prompt to generate a quiz in CSV format

Tags: llama-2

I want to generate quizzes and obtain the output in CSV format using llama2.

I want to obtain something like this:

```
1;What is the primary function of the mitochondria in a cell?;a) To synthesize proteins;b) To store genetic information;c) To generate energy through cellular respiration;c
2;Which of the following nerve cells is responsible for transmitting visual information from the eye to the brain?;a) Optic nerve;b) Olfactory nerve;c) Vagus nerve;a
```

this is what I get:

```
1; What is the primary function of the mitochondria in a cell?
a) To synthesize proteins; b) To store genetic information; c) To generate energy through 
cellular respiration. Correct answer: c) To generate energy through cellular respiration.
2; Which of the following nerve cells is responsible for transmitting visual information from 
the eye to the brain?
a) Optic nerve; b) Olfactory nerve; c) Vagus nerve. Correct answer: a) Optic nerve.
```

this is the prompt I am using:

```
ollama run llama2 "create two easy questions on biology. Each question should contain three answers and only one correct. Present questions in semicolon-delimited CSV in the following order: first the question number, then the question itself, then the three answers, then the number of the correct answer."
```

I have tried hundreds of variations of this. None generates what I need.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've discovered that I can give an example, like this:

```
ollama run llama2 "create two easy questions on biology. Each question should contain three answers and only one correct. Present questions in semicolon-delimited CSV as in the following example: 1;What is the primary function of the mitochondria in a cell?;a) To synthesize proteins;b) To store genetic information;c) To generate energy through cellular respiration;c"
```

The result provided by this prompt is closer to what I want, but the correct answer is never C, always A or B.

Comment: You might try adding to the prompt something like “Randomize the placement of correct answers so that there is a near equal chance of the correct answer being any of the letters: A, B, C”. I phrased it as “near equal” because we don't want it to get confused if it can't be made precisely equal. You can experiment with different wordings. “Even distribution” also comes to mind. On a side note, I feel like if you're doing this at scale the incorporation of a *random seed* might be a good idea at some point.

Comment: Here is [a reddit thread about LLM + CSV](https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/13nld5x/how_do_i_get_local_llm_to_analyze_an_whole_excel/) that points out how token context is usually the limiting factor when it comes to this kind of thing. The thread is now 10 months old. With newer models coming out the possibilities are likely to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give it some examples of what you want so it knows what your idea of what the result should be.

It was able to do it with this prompt on chatbot arena:

> Create two easy questions on biology in a semicolon-delimited CSV format.
>
> FORMAT: question number;question;first answer;second answer;third answer;letter of the correct answer
>
> EXAMPLE 1: 1;What is the primary function of the mitochondria in a cell?;a) To synthesize proteins;b) To store genetic information;c) To generate energy through cellular respiration;c
>
> EXAMPLE 2: 2;What is the main purpose of photosynthesis in plants?;a) To communicate with other plants through chemical signals;b) To purify the air around them;c) To convert sunlight into chemical energy;a;
>
> ANSWER:

[image]